# What is a better attempt to create a sigma-algebra?

Tags: measure-theory

I am trying to create a sigma algebra of a simple nature, such that each element represents a subset of $R^d$.

I tried to start with the set of convex hulls, but that's not good, because the complement of a convex set is not convex.

Then, I thought maybe convex hulls and their complements, but that doesn't seem to work either, because the union of two convex hull does not have to be a convex hull, naturally.

I am happy to define my sigma-algebra based on a principal, finite set of vectors $v_1, ... v_n$ (for example, all convex hulls that have vertices among $v_i$).

I know this is vague, but I am really trying to avoid having to use a Borel sigma-algebra, I just want something simple that is finite in nature.

Is there some standard sigma-algebra I could use?

Comment: $\{\emptyset, \mathbb  R^{d},A,A^{c}\}$ is a sigma algebra for any set $A \subset \mathbb  R^{d}$

Comment: "...but I am really trying to avoid having to use a Borel sigma-algebra..." Not so easy I think, but not impossible if I understand well. Have a look at [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/87838/40263). Btw, what is your objection against Borel sigma-algebras?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most standard way to construct a $\sigma$-algebra is to consider some sets to be "measurable" and then to take the minimal $\sigma$-algebra which contains those. This way is general as any $\sigma$-algebra can be constructed this way.

Observe first, that $P(\mathbb{R}^n)$ is a $\sigma$-algebra which contains every subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$. Now suppose that $(\mathcal{F}_i)_{i\in I}$ is a family of $\sigma$-algebras. Then it is not hard to show that the intersection $\bigcap_{i\in I} \mathcal{F}_i$ is a $\sigma$-algebra.

This lead to the following natural definition: Let $A\subseteq P(\mathbb{R}^n)$ be any family of subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$. It could be the open sets, or the convex hulls, or whatever you can think about. Then define a $\sigma$-algebra $\sigma(A)$ to be the intersection over all $\sigma$-algebras which contains $A$. In other words $\sigma(A)$ is the minimal $\sigma$-algebra which contains the elements in $A$.

So here are few instances that might interest you:

If $A=\{B\}$ is a single set then $\sigma(A) = \{\emptyset,\mathbb{R}^n,B,B^c\}$. (see @Kavi Rama Murthy 's comment)

If $A$ is a $\sigma$-algebra, then $\sigma(A)=A$. In other words **you can construct any $\sigma$-algebra that way**.

If $A$ are the open sets, then $\sigma(A)$ is the Borel-$\sigma$ algebra (but I see you said you want to avoid it).

If $n=1$ and $A$ contains all intervals $[a,b],(a,b),(a,b],(b,a]$ then $\sigma(A)$ is the Lebesgue $\sigma$-algebra. One can extend this to higher dimensions by taking products of the above. In general, if one consider a $\sigma$-algebra on $\mathcal{F}_X$ on $X$ and $\mathcal{F}_Y$ on $Y$. The only natural way to construct a $\sigma$-algebra on $X\times Y$ is by taking $\sigma(\mathcal{F}_X\times \mathcal{F}_Y)$.

One last point, it is also possible to replace the family of set $A$ with a family of functions. That is, instead of pointing out which sets you choose to be measurable, you can point out which functions are to be measurable. In other words, if $A$ is a family of functions $f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow Y$ for some measure space $Y$, one can define $\sigma(A)$ to be the smallest $\sigma$-algebra for which all $f\in A$ are measurables ( by taking an intersection of all the relevant $\sigma$-algebras).